# Object declared as public in Project1 Class1 always shows as null when called from Project2 Class2

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, .net-4.5

I'm using C#, .Net framework 4.5
I have two projects in my solution, let's say Project1 and Project2, where Project1 is added as reference for Project2.
In Project1 I have a static class "Global", in which I declared a public static List of object:

```
namespace Solution.Project1
{
    public static class Global
    {
        public static List<OM.User> AllActiveUsers;
    }
}
```

In Project2, I also have a static class "UserFactory", in which I have a static method that uses the "AllActiveUsers"variable from Project1:

```
namespace Sol.Project2
{
    public static class UserFactory
    {
    public static List<OM.User> GetUsersDetails()
        {
            List<OM.User> ret = new List<OM.User>();

            foreach (OM.User user in Project1.Global.AllActiveUsers) //here is the problem
            {
                //TODO: write logic
            }

            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

I made sure that AllActiveUsers is initiated and filled with 5 User objects, although when called here in Project2 it shows as null!
What would cause that?

**UPDATE:**
Sorry I think I got it, I forgot that the method in Project2 is not called directly, it's called through a webservice:

```
await ModMain.objWebService.GetUsersDetailsAsync();
```

but if I call my method from UserFactory right away:

```
UserFactory.GetUsersDetails();
```

then AllActiveUsers is not being null.
Is it what's causing this issue?
Maybe this post is transformed to be an information about issue when calling method from webservice.

Comment: `I made sure that AllActiveUsers is initiated and filled with 5 User objects,`. Can you show us where you do this?

Comment: Is your static property is not modified between the time you check the variable and the time you see it as null ? To check this, you transform temporary your static member into a "get/set" property, and then add a breakpoint in the "set" code.

Comment: @JurgenCamilleri I initialized it in my Program.cs, when the application is started.

Comment: @PaulDS I added set and get and set was accessed once when I filled the variable only

Comment: This is weird... You can try to create a "static readonly" field in the Global class, with inline initialization. If you doesn't get the problem with this, try to remove the "readonly" keyword. If you doesn't get the problem either, that means that the problem doesn't come from the multi-project use.

Comment: @JurgenCamilleri Please check the update I made to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search, I think I found the problem.

The static variables in web services applications have a lifetime link to the worker proccess, so they may be reinitialized automatically. They should not be used for this type of application. One of the sources : [Web service variable shared for the lifetime of the webservice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292831/web-service-variable-shared-for-the-lifetime-of-the-webservice)

A solution might be to use the application state to store objects between requests : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13402/Building-web-services-with-persistent-state

Comment: Thanks a lot for this info and for your research.

Answer (score 0):

It must be where you are initializing your list. You say program.cs but I have replicated your code like this.

Project 2:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConsoleApplication1.Global.AllActiveUsers = new List<string>() { "test1", "test2" };
        UserFactory.GetUsersDetails();
    }
}

public static class UserFactory
{
    public static List<string> GetUsersDetails()
    {
        List<string> ret = new List<string>();

        foreach (string user in ConsoleApplication1.Global.AllActiveUsers) //here is the problem
        {
            //TODO: write logic
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Project 1

```
public static class Global
{
    public static List<string> AllActiveUsers;
}
```

And you this works fine as I am initializing the list inline before the call to the static method is made.

If you provide exactly where you are initializing the list then it might shed more light on your issue.

Comment: Yes I did that too and worked fine, but as I added in my update, I think the problem is that the method is being called through webservice, so if I change UserFactory.GetUsersDetails() to await ModMain.objWebService.GetUsersDetailsAsync() I get the problem.